# How Service worker prevent 'fetch' from consuming too much disk space?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

May I know what is the strategy that can be used to prevent `addEventListener('fetch'` && `cache.put(` from filling up user's disk space? Is there anyway to set expirary for the each request in cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the service worker spec](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cache-lifetimes):

> The Cache objects are exactly what authors have to manage themselves.
>   The Cache objects do not get updated unless authors explicitly request
>   them to be. The Cache objects do not expire unless authors delete the
>   entries.

Note that [the browser can throw your cache away](http://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#cache-persistence) if it wants to (and you should assume that sometimes it will), especially if it decides you're storing too much - it's not going to let you fill up the user's entire drive.

There do not appear do be any methods for examining the size of the cache either. However note that there are related specifications in the works, for example for the [Quota Management API](https://w3c.github.io/quota-api/). The article by Jake Archibald linked above gives the following example of using the this API (which would give you a result for *all* site storage, not just your caches):

```
navigator.storageQuota.queryInfo("temporary").then(function(info) {
  console.log(info.quota);
  // Result: <quota in bytes>
  console.log(info.usage);
  // Result: <used data in bytes>
});
```

However I just tried this in Chrome Canary and `storageQuota` was undefined - I don't think this is implemented anywhere yet. Hopefully someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also please note that the [Storage Spec](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/) is being developed to unify the separate approaches of browser storage, and (at least in part) to provide a way for browsers to define quotas and eviction strategies for the different client-side storage types.

Comment: Thanks. It does look like that's the direction things are going. So the request looks like it'll be pretty similar, except maybe start with `navigator.storage.estimate().then(...)`. In any case definitely not finished yet.

Comment: I had read jakearchibald blog before posted this question. However, it still does not answer my question. Should one just fetch everything and let the browser decides whether to scrap objects in cache?

Comment: The answer is that 1) you cannot set an expiration, and 2) you cannot fill up the user's drive because eventually the browser will throw the cache away. The browser will throw everything away at the same time. If that's OK with you, then yes, you can just cache everything. If you're not OK with that, then you should consider one of the other strategies in that article. Of course, the browser could throw your stuff away no matter what, it's just more likely to happen more often if you store a lot.

Comment: @cometta if what you want is a way to combine caching on fetch with a strategy for cleaning up old assets occasionally, I recommend you look at how it's done here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/read-through-caching/service-worker.js